# asp.net FriendlyUrl is duplicating # tag

Tags: asp.net, webforms, friendly-url

I have a simple link with a # tag in the menu.

```
<a runat="server" href="~/Video/#assemble">Assemble</a>
```

It works fine from other pages and the FriendlyUrl forms URL as;

```
localhost/Video/#assemble
```

The problem comes when the same menu item is selected from the landed page.  The URL form is;

```
localhost/Video/#assemble#assemble
```

Any clue as to how to get rid of the second # tag when selecting from the same page?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
<a runat="server" href="~/Video/#assemble">Assemble</a>
```

Use

```
<a runat="server" href="~/Video#assemble">Assemble</a>
```